# Открытие фотографии в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Есть оформление, вот код, который созданный в `Qt Designer`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action1.setObjectName("action1")
        self.action2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action2.setObjectName("action2")
        self.action3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action3.setObjectName("action3")
        self.action4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action4.setObjectName("action4")
        self.action5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action5.setObjectName("action5")
        self.action6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action6.setObjectName("action6")
        self.action7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action7.setObjectName("action7")
        self.action8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action8.setObjectName("action8")
        self.action9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action9.setObjectName("action9")
        self.action10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action10.setObjectName("action10")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action1)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action2)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action3)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action4)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action5)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action6)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action7)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action8)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action9)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action10)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать снимок"))
        self.action1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 снимок"))
        self.action2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.action3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.action4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.action5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.action6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.action7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.action8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.action9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.action10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Как добавить открытие фотографии в этой программе, при нажатии на клавиши?

Вот есть код, который открывает в программе фотографию, как реализовать этот функционал в 1 программе?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
 
class Example(QWidget):
    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):      
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("0.bmp")
        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        
        self.move(100, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если модулю, который вы назвали оформление дать название, например: `questions_910942_ui.py`, то `main.py` может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

from questions_910942_ui import Ui_MainWindow              # <-------

class Example(QMainWindow):                                #(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.image = "ima.jpg"

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.action1.triggered.connect(self.load_image1)
        self.ui.action2.triggered.connect(self.load_image2)
        # ...
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        #hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.image)        #("0.bmp")
        self.lbl = QLabel()                 #(self)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)

#        self.setLayout(hbox)
#        self.move(100, 200)
#        self.show()        

    def load_image1(self):
        self.image = "ima.jpg"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()
    def load_image2(self):
        self.image = "E:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"
        self.lbl.hide()
        self.initUI()
    # ...    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]